# How to connect SharePoint Excel file to SSIS Excel source?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, ssis

I need to connect my SharePoint xls file as a source to SSIS. How can I achieve this?

I referred to these links for connection source:

- http://www.techbrothersit.com/2016/07/how-to-download-file-from-sharepoint-by.html
- https://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-microsoft-sharepoint/help-manual

I have given the SharePoint link and username in the HTTP Connection Manager.

I get the 403 forbidden error while following the above link. Is there any way to connect?

> The remote server returned an error (403) Forbidden.

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The error that you have shared is from the out-of-box HTTP connection manager. If you have our SSIS Productivity Pack and SharePoint toolkit installed, you could directly read an Excel file using our Premium Excel Source component, which can be then be passed to the SSIS pipeline.